# PHP mail sending when product got expire

Tags: php, mysql, email

i want to send the mail , when product got expire from before and ondate and after day, in php i was used datediff mysql function with php, but if product expire date comes like 31-1-2012 , the differ value is not suit for my coding , plz help how to solve it , 
This is my coding

```
<?php

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplier_product_det");
$results = mysql_num_rows($sql);
//echo '<script>alert("'.$results.'")</script>';
if ($results > 0)
{   

        for($i=0;$i<$results;$i++)
        {
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
             /* print_r($rows['expired_on']);?><br /> <?*/
             $exdate = $rows['expired_on'];
             $curdate = date('Y-m-d'); 
             $datedif = mysql_query("select datediff('".$curdate."','".$exdate."')");
             while( $date = mysql_fetch_array($datedif) )
             {
                //echo $date['0'];
                //echo $rows['pro_code'];
                if (($date['0'])== 1)
                {

                    if(($rows['mailcount'])!== $curdate)
                    {
                        $to = $rows['supplier'];
                        $subject = "Product Expire Intimation";
                        $message = "Dear Mr/Miss/Mrs
                        The Following Your Product Expired 
                        Product Code:".$rows['pro_code']."
                        Product Name:".$rows['product_name']."
                        Product Expire Date:".$rows['expired_on']."";               
                        $from = "tone@bgrow.com";
                        $headers = "From:" . $from;
                        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
                        $checkdate = mysql_query("update supplier_product_det set mailcount ='".$curdate."' where id='".$rows['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                    }


                    //echo $rows['supplier'];

                }
                    if (($date['0'])== 0)
                {
                    if(($rows['mailcount'])!== $curdate)
                    {
                        $to = $rows['supplier'];
                        $subject = "Product Expire Intimation";
                        $message = "Dear Mr/Miss/Mrs
                        The Following Your Product Expired
                        Product Code:".$rows['pro_code']."
                        Product Name:".$rows['product_name']."
                        Product Expire Date:".$rows['expired_on']."";
                        $from = "tone@bgrow.com";
                        $headers = "From:" . $from;
                        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
                        $checkdate = mysql_query("update supplier_product_det set mailcount ='".$curdate."' where id='".$rows['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                    }


                    //echo $rows['supplier'];

                }
                    if (($date['0'])== -1)
                {
                    if(($rows['mailcount'])!== $curdate)
                    {
                        $to = $rows['supplier'];
                        $subject = "Product Expire Intimation";
                        $message = "Dear Mr/Miss/Mrs
                        The Following Your Product will Expire Today 
                        Product Code:".$rows['pro_code']."
                        Product Name:".$rows['product_name']."
                        Product Expire Date:".$rows['expired_on']."";
                        $from = "tone@bgrow.com";
                        $headers = "From:" . $from;
                        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
                        $checkdate = mysql_query("update supplier_product_det set mailcount ='".$curdate."' where id='".$rows['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                    }


                    //echo $rows['supplier'];

                }
             }

            }

        }

}
?>
```

Comment: What is the schema of the database? Also, is there a reason you're not deferring this processing to the database? (after all, you could modify the first query to only bring back the rows for those that are about to expire, so that you don't have to do a second query just to do a date comparison)

Comment: your second select is not needed. add a column to your first select statement that will return now()-expired_on

Answer (score 1):

Write your second select query as follows

```
SELECT DATEDIFF($exdate, CURRENT_DATE) as diff;
```

Also, no need to write separate select query you can get same column in first query itself as

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, DATEDIFF(expired_on, CURRENT_DATE) as diff
FROM supplier_product_det
```

You may need to change position of expired_on and CURRENT_DATE to get correct diff value

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
PHP: $now = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'));
```

-

```
SQL: WHERE $now >= DATE_FORMAT(expires, "%Y-%m-%d")
```